# How to purchase premium features of an Android app for a group of people?

Tags: applications, google-play-store

For a research project, we are utilizing an app available in the Google Play Store to collect data. However, to do this properly, we need to provide all participants with the paid full version of the app.

One version would be buying Google Play gift codes and telling our participants to use them on the full version.

However, I was wondering if there is any alternative way to directly enable them to download the premium version such as buying the version for the Google Play user with the email address example@gmail.com.

Comment: There was a functionality to manage app licenses in a managed play store environment but that feature had been dropped some years ago: https://support.google.com/googleplay/work/answer/6150398?hl=en

Comment: I just noticed that in your title you are talking about "premium features" (which sounds like in-app purchases) but in your question later you are talking about "paid full version of the app" (which seems to refer to a non-free app you have to pay only once for download).  As there may be a difference in potential answers it may be better to update your question and make it clear if you are talking about in-app purchase or a paid app.